# Windows authentication with ASP.Net MVC 4 with VS 2012 and above

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

Writing this as a question and answering it self, because there were two steps i followed to resolve the issue, which was not available together.

Was developing an application in ASP.Net MVC 4 [internet app using razor view] using Visual Studio 2012.

The default web.config entries for `<authentication>` was as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

I needed windows authentication for the application. Hence, changed the mode to Windows

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

With the above settings, `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` was `false` `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` was empty string.

Comment: OK and did you set up NTLM authentication on the webserver?

Comment: @DavidHirst : Have posted the steps followed as the answer to make it run locally. Did not set up NTLM authentication on webserver. The following process was required to make the application run in debug mode locally.

Answer (score 5):

```
Select the web project and press F4.
```

Make the following changes:

```
Anonymous Authentication : Disabled, 
Windows Authentication : Enabled .
```

If the application is tried to run with the above changes, you will get HTTP 404 error and application will be redirected to domainname/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f.

Along with above changes there are two more keys which is to be added in the `<appSettings>` section in the web.config file.

```
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="enablesimplemembership" value="false"/>
```

Now if you run the application you will be an authenticated user and also get the name.

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated will be true
```

and

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name will have the user name.
```